# Python decoding UDP

Tags: python, sockets, networking, udp

code:

```
import socket, binascii, struct

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)
while True:
    print s.recv(2048)
```

---

output:

> Ek�9@@�F5��W�jq��� stackexchangecom�      electronics �
>   h  h
>
> stackexchangecomDa�scifi ET@@�<���� stackoverflowcom���meta
>                       ,��� stackoverflowcom�A���meta
>                       ,��� stackexchangecomG��security Ee@@�+���� stackexchangecom���scifi

as you can see some of the data has been decoded/interpreted but the rest isn't not sure as to why

Can anyone help?

Comment: Have you looked into requests? http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/#

Comment: do you know what format this is all in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're printing raw UDP packets, which contain arbitrary binary data. Some of those bytes are in the [printable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_characters) range, but those that aren't in that range get converted into �.

You can get a better look at that data by printing its [representation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-repr), which shows the printable bytes as normal and shows the unprintable ones as hexadecimal escape codes. To do that, change your `print` statement to:

```
    print repr(s.recv(2048))
```

I suspect you'd like to actually decode those packets. That's quite possible, but it's a bit technical, and you should probably study the topic a bit first. :) This article by Silver Moon, [Code a network packet sniffer in python for Linux](http://www.binarytides.com/python-packet-sniffer-code-linux/), looks quite helpful.